# IE8 CSS Shadow not displaying correctly on a parent div

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Here is my site: http://uwf.edu/honors/thesis_submission/

In firefox, everything is absolutely great. However, in IE8 the shadow does not surround the bottom footer div inside my container.

```
<div class = "container">
    ...
    <div style = "clear:both"></div>
    <div class = "..." id = "footer">
    </div>

</div>
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: That missing `>` was a sneaky distraction..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 doesn't natively support the `box-shadow` CSS property.

I note that you're using a `filter` style to achieve the same effect.

Firstly, for IE8 you should use `-ms-filter` instead of just `filter`, and also enclose the filter value in quotes, like so:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#cccccc', Direction= 135, Strength=5)";
```

You will need to also keep your existing `filter` style if you want to support IE6 and IE7.

Secondly, I would strongly suggest using a product like [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) in order to add support for the standard CSS `box-shadow` to IE. This will drastically simplify your stylesheets and make them easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions...I made the changes, however those had toe same results. (Better shadow though! :) )  I'll look into the CSS3Pie

Comment: I used the CSS3Pie and now it looks wonderful! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is messed.

it should be 
`<div style = "clear:both"></div>`

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing that out, but that wasn't the problem. Just a typo on my part. :P